# KineticJs : From click event to multitouch for my rotation

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, kineticjs, multi-touch

I have this click event in my code where when i click my puzzle rotate 90degree, but i want it to be touch, how should i do it? thanks

```
    piecesArray[i][j].shape.on("mousedown", function(){
                this.moveToTop();
                });
            piecesArray[i][j].shape.on("click", function(){
                this.moveToTop();
                this.rotateDeg(90)
                });   
            layer.add(piecesArray[i][j].shape);
        }
```

Ps: my jsfiddle doesnt work, but if you wanna see my code its here : http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/5/

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
piecesArray[i][j].shape.on('touchstart', function() {
    this.moveToTop();
    this.rotateDeg(90)
});
```

or this:

```
stage.getContent().addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    this.moveToTop();
    this.rotateDeg(90)
}, false);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but do you have any idea which i could use 2 fingers touch to rotate it? thanks